# How can i assign a different database to each different user that logs in using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to come up with a system using PHP and MySQL,
but I have different database tables, so I want to make it that each user that logins it is appointed to a different database according to their login id,

how can I do it

Comment: Why does each user need their own DB, on even their own table if this is misphrased? This sounds like a bad design.

Comment: i just needed each user to have a different database because they will have to access different information, infact we create for them a database which they have to upload once they login using the temporary password and their loginid  we give them, do u have a better desgin??

Comment: Use a `where` clause on your queries and only give them records they should have access to. A DB per user is going to be unmanageable.

Comment: i know but tell me how i can do that??

Comment: You need to save the user ID together with the information in a separate column, for example "userID". Now, when the user logs in, you would to something like "SELECT * FROM [table name] WHERE userID = [the user id of the user]"

Comment: i need to select the database name for that